# In Python's DEAP, how can I have an individual with multiple genes, eg a "Genotype"?

Tags: python, numpy, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm, deap

**TLDR:**

How can I use [DEAP](https://github.com/DEAP/deap) to evolve *Genotypes* instead of just *Genes*, for example `(Gene1, Gene2, ...)` or `{'gene1':..., 'gene2':...}`

A minimal example would be to create an evolution of DEAP's [OneMax](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples/ga_onemax_numpy.html) example, using a Genotype of `(np.ndarray(10), np.ndarray(42))`, where `Genotype[0]` only mates with `Genotype[0]`, `...[1]` with `...[1]`, and the entire Genotype can be used in evaluating fitness.

---

In Python's [DEAP](https://github.com/DEAP/deap), the common use case is to have a "gene", for example a single list, that can be mated, mutated, and evaluated for fitness.

My general problem is, I'd like to use a heterogeneous list / tuple / dictionary of genes, each with their own type, and functions such as mating are only defined by type.

Specifically, I have a "neural network" I'd like to represent with

1. one gene for **neuron** parameters
2. and one gene for **network** structure + parameters.

The types (borrowing from typed languages' syntax) might be

```
NeuronGene  :: np.ndarray(n)
NetworkGene :: np.ndarray((n, n))
```

And those arrays are [structured numpy arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#structured-datatypes), with various keys, eg: `np.dtype([('a', int), ('b', float), ...])`, so at each index in the `NeuronGene`, I have a dictionary-like parameter with keys `{'a':..., 'b':..., ...}`. If this complicates the question too much, I'd still love to see how to have a genotype of generic `np.ndarray`s.

A "genotype" could be like `Individual :: (NeuronGene, NetworkGene)`, and

a proper `mate` function might be defined like:

```
mate :: NeuronGene  -> NeuronGene  -> NeuronGene
mate :: NetworkGene -> NetworkGene -> NetworkGene
```

As a minimal example, I've tried to duplicate DEAP's [OneMax](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples/ga_onemax_numpy.html) problem, but using a genotype of 2 genes. So 2 different-sized `np.ndarray`s that each are trying to maximize their sums individually. Even reading through [DEAP's docs](https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/basic/part1.html) and [codebase](https://github.com/DEAP/deap/tree/c573147b4ccde6bb38490db5941d6879022c0eab/examples), my code isn't worth posting.

For a simple problem like this minimal example, sure you could use one gene of length `n + m`, but in my actual case, I have a gene that's `(1D array, 2D array)`, and mutation/mating means something different for each individual gene in that genotype.

I should mention that my `eval` function simply resolves to one single fitness function, although I'd think a proper general answer could optimize for multiple.

```
eval :: Genotype -> Float
# or
eval :: Genotype -> (Float, Float, ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I completely understand what you need but this might help:

1) used dict as the individual container, make your custom initDict function

2) write your custom dict versions of mating and individual evaluation functions that do different things to different keys of the individual

Below is an example of creating dict-like individual of random arrays and evaluating them. You can then modify DEAP base algorithms for mating, mutation etc. so that they can work with dicts the way you want.

```
from deap import base
from deap import creator
from deap import tools
import numpy as np

def initDict(container, func, dim):
    return container(zip(dim.keys(), map(lambda val: func(val), dim.values())))

def evalIndividual(individual):
    return [individual[key].sum() for key in individual.keys()]

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,1.0))  # fitness
creator.create("Individual", dict, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

#function for generation arrays of random values and random size in each dimension (min 2, max 10) but fixed number of dimensions by the dim argument
toolbox.register("attr_random", lambda dim: np.random.rand(*np.random.randint(2,10,dim)))
toolbox.register("individual", initDict, creator.Individual, toolbox.attr_random, dim = dict(neuron = 2, network = 3))
ind = toolbox.individual()
ind.fitness.values = evalIndividual(ind)
print(ind.fitness)
```